# How to compile ffmpeg examples outside the default folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have successfully built FFmpeg on Ubuntu and `make examples` works. I have tested the example "encode_video.c", it generates several files like "encode_video", "encode_video.d", "encode_video.o", "encode_video_g" and "encode_video". The "encode_video" file works well.

However, when I want to build this example in other places manually instead of the command `make examples`. The compilation could be completed. But when I run the "encoding" file, it will always show "Codec xxx not found".

I use the command `gcc -o encoding encode_video.c -lavcodec -lavutil`.

Here is part of the lines of the "encode_video.c".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   const char *filename, *codec_name;
   const AVCodec *codec;
   AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
   int i, ret, x, y;
   FILE *f;
   AVFrame *frame;
   AVPacket *pkt;
   uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

   if (argc <= 2) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <output file> <codec name>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
   }
   filename = argv[1];
   codec_name = argv[2];

   /* find the mpeg1video encoder */
   codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name);
   if (!codec) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Codec '%s' not found\n", codec_name);
       exit(1);
   }

   c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
   if (!c) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
       exit(1);
   }

   pkt = av_packet_alloc();
   if (!pkt)
       exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can attest that I am having this *same* issue as well on both Ubuntu and mac os -- specifically, how can one move the ffmpeg examples out of the default directory tree (~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/doc/examples) so you can modify and test them against your own programs.

Believe this lays in modifying the makefiles -- but which ones need to be modified -- and what needs to change -- is not clear.